# Best ways to compress css and js files on MOSS 2007 site

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I'm trying to improve my MOSS 2007 site performance. Is there a working module of compressing css and js files on the fly or atleast compress the files after build and wsp package should contain compressed css and js files.

Answer (score 0):

I use web essentials.

you should be able to use it in a sharepoint solution as well

http://vswebessentials.com